# instalación de certificado ssl en windows server 2016

Tags: servidor, certificado-ssl

Alguién que conozca el procedimiento para instalar un certicado ssl emitido por godaddy en un servidor: win server 2016

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa que intento instalar un certificado sll emitido por godaddy en win server 2016, me pasan las siguientes instrucciónes ya que tengo IIS10 https://co.godaddy.com/help/instalar-manualmente-un-certificado-ssl-en-mi-servidor-iis-10-27349  pero no lo puedo instalar correctamente porque despues del paso 30 ya no veo el certificado, no lo puedo vincular en el último paso